# ¿Cómo funciona el algoritmo de quicksort?

Tags: java, algoritmos

Tengo esta clase que implementa el método de ordenamiento *quicksort* pero no me queda claro.  ¿Cómo es que ordena los valores?

```
public class QuickSortClass {
    public static void quickSort(int[] vector, int izquierda, int derecha) {
        int pivote = vector[izquierda];
        int i = izquierda;
        int j = derecha;
        int auxIntercambio;
        while (i < j) {
            while (vector[i] <= pivote && i < j) {
                i++;
            }
            while (vector[j] > pivote) {
                j--;
            }
            if (i < j) {
                auxIntercambio = vector[i];
                vector[i] = vector[j];
                vector[j] = auxIntercambio;
            }
        }
        vector[izquierda] = vector[j];
        vector[j] = pivote;
        if (izquierda < j - 1) {
            quickSort(vector, izquierda, j - 1);
        }
        if (j + 1 < derecha) {
            quickSort(vector, j + 1, derecha);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numeros = new int[40];
        Random rnd = new Random();
        System.out.println("Vector desordenado");
        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
            numeros[i] = rnd.nextInt(50);
            System.out.print(numeros[i] + " ");
        }   
        QuickSortClass.quickSort(numeros, 0, numeros.length - 1);
        System.out.println("\nVector Ordenado");
        for (int n : numeros) {
            System.out.print(n + " ");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hay una entrada muy detallada en Wikipedia: [*Quicksort*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).

Answer (score 12):

El algoritmo quicksort parte de un concepto muy simple. Asumiendo que tienes un arreglo A:

1. Te ubicas en un elemento A[i] donde 0 < i < longitud de A. Este elemento será el pivote
2. Colocar todos los elementos A[j] > A[i] en las casillas superiores o "a la derecha" de A[i], mientras que todos los elementos A[k] < A[i] se colocan en las casillas inferiores o "a la izquierda" de A[i]. Los elementos iguales pueden estar a su derecha o izquierda. Es (muy) probable que el pivote cambie de lugar para satisfacer estas condiciones, es decir, el valor de `i` sea modificado.
3. Luego de realizados los cambios, se tiene A1 que es el subconjunto de A desde A[0] hasta A[i-1] y A2 que es el subconjunto de A[i+1] hasta A[longitud de A - 1]. Aplicar este proceso para A1 y A2.

Esto se explica muy bien en [la animación de Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#/media/File:Sorting_quicksort_anim.gif).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Por en:User:RolandH, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=1965827

Veamos como el código que provees en tu pregunta corresponde a una implementación del algoritmo:

```
public static void quickSort(int[] vector, int izquierda, int derecha) {
    //1. Elegir el pivote
    int pivote = vector[izquierda];
    //2. Los elementos > al pivote van a su derecha, los < a su izquierda
    //esta parte de la implementación es el corazón del ordenamiento
    //se utilizan variables auxiliares:
    //- i para controlar los elementos a la izquierda del pivote
    //- j para controlar los elementos a la derecha del pivote
    int i = izquierda;
    int j = derecha;
    //esta variable debería tener un alcance menor pero se respeta la implementación
    int auxIntercambio;
    //mientras que deban evaluarse los elementos en el arreglo
    //para ubicar al nuevo pivote
    while (i < j) {
        //mientras que el elemento vector[i] sea menor o igual al pivote
        //se aumenta el valor de i
        //cuando este loop se detenga, el elemento en vector[i]
        //es mayor a pivote y deberá ir a su derecha
        while (vector[i] <= pivote && i < j) {
            i++;
        }
        //mientras que el elemento vector[j] sea mayor al pivote
        //se desminuye el valor de j
        //cuando este loop se detenga, el elemento en vector[j]
        //es menor o igual a pivote y deberá ir a su izquierda
        while (vector[j] > pivote) {
            j--;
        }
        //siempre y cuando i sea menor a j, se hace un cambio de los elementos
        //puesto que el elemento en vector[i] debe ir a la derecha
        //y vector[j] a la izquierda
        if (i < j) {
            //nota: auxIntercambio podría estar declarada aquí ya que NO tiene otro alcance
            auxIntercambio = vector[i];
            vector[i] = vector[j];
            vector[j] = auxIntercambio;
        }
    }
    //Por los ciclos anteriores, j llegó a una posición donde su elemento (i.e. vector[j]) 
    //es menor o igual al pivote, actualizamos entonces la posición del pivote, mandando vector[j] 
    //a la ubicación del pivote y viceversa (el pivote a la posicion vector[j])
    vector[izquierda] = vector[j];
    vector[j] = pivote;
    //3. Para A1 y A2, aplicar el mismo proceso.
    if (izquierda < j - 1) {
        //quicksort aplicado a A1
        quickSort(vector, izquierda, j - 1);
    }
    if (j + 1 < derecha) {
        //quicksort aplicado a A2
        quickSort(vector, j + 1, derecha);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

La estrategia de este algoritmo es "divide y conquistarás", en lugar de tratar de ordenar una sola lista grande, la separa varias veces en listas más pequeñas parcialmente ordenadas hasta que tienes listas de un solo elemento que ya se encuentra en la posición correcta.  Esto es mas claro con un ejemplo:

Teniendo el vector desordenado inicial

```
[5, 1, 3, 9, 6, 10, 2, 8, 4, 7]
```

Se divide en dos partes, tomando un elemento de manera arbitraria (normalmente el del medio)

```
[5, 1, 3, 9, 6] [10, 2, 8, 4, 7]
```

Ahora utilizando el valor seleccionado (pivote) "6", movemos todo lo que sea menor o igual en la izquierda y lo que sea mayor a la derecha

```
[5, 1, 3, 4, 2, 6] [10, 9, 8, 7]
```

Este proceso se repite por cada sublista

```
[5, 1, 3][4, 2, 6] | [10, 9][8, 7]

[2, 1, 3][4, 5, 6] | [8, 7, 9] [10]

[2, 1][3] | [4, 5][6] | [8, 7][9] | [10]

[1][2] | [3] | [4][5] | [6] | [7][8] | [9] | [10]
```

Al ir moviendo todo lo que es que menor a un lado y todo lo que es mayor al otro eventualmente se logra ordenar todo.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno, a ver, vamos a suponer que tenemos el siguiente array de enteros:

```
int[] numeros = { 20, 35, 10, 15, 25, 30 }; // Desordenado.
```

> El algoritmo quicksort comienza 'cogiendo' como principal valor el indicando en el parámetro, vamos a suponer que es el primero, el **20**.
>
> Realiza una búsqueda de izquierda a derecha y encuentra el **35**, como nodo superior y realiza una búsqueda de derecha a izquierda y encuentra el **15** como nodo menor.
>
> Los intercambia y continúa la búsqueda con los nuevos cambios:

```
int[] numeros = { 20, 15, 10, 35, 25, 30 }
```

> Partiendo de este punto, el array va quedando partido en 2 subarrays, de los cuales pasaran por el mismo proceso hasta que esté ordenador de menor a mayor.
>
> Resultado:

```
int[] numeros = { 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35 } // Ordenado
```

Lo recomendado, al llamar a la funciona es dar un valor intermedio, la mediana.

***Para mayor información, como te han dejado en algún comentario:***

[Enlace a Wikipedia: Quicksort](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)

[Enlace a Algolist: Quicksort](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Quicksort)

[Enlace a PuntoComEsUnLenguage: Quicksort](http://puntocomnoesunlenguaje.blogspot.com.es/2012/12/java-quicksort.html) *(donde me he apoyado para responderte)*

Comment: No entiendo cómo esto responde a la pregunta: *cómo es que el código ordena los valores*